# Node.js allow only supported methods

Tags: node.js, rest, if-statement

The following is the start of an API. I'm trying to write as part of my lessons, the course is strictly node.js without any frameworks.

My attempt is to reject request with 400 if the request method is not allowed.
(if method in `methoArr` then allow else reject)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
var os = require('os');
var helpers = require('./helperFunctions');
var cl = console.log.bind(console);

//init server and listen 
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //define req.url as array
    let qs = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    //deal with favico request
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'
        });
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    //return if method not allowed
    const methodArr = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'];
    var allowedMethod = true;
    cl(typeof req.method, typeof methodArr[0]);
    if (
        req.url != methodArr[0] &&
        req.url != methodArr[1] &&
        req.url != methodArr[2] &&
        req.url != methodArr[3] &&
        req.url != methodArr[4] &&
        req.url != methodArr[5]
    ) {
        allowedMethod = false;
    }
    if (allowedMethod) {
        // cl('req.url: ', qs, 'helpers: ', helpers, 'req method: ', req.method);
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write('end url: ' + qs + ' method: ' + req.method);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(400);
        res.write(req.method + ' method not allowed\n' + 'methodArr#: ' + methodArr[0]);
    }
    res.end();
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

The `if` logic seems ok but obviously not...tried a switch but same issue.
I would appreciate if you can explain the error in my logic.

Comment: also tried

`if (methodArr.includes(req.url)) allowedMethod = false;`

instead of:

`    if (
        req.url != methodArr[0] &&
        req.url != methodArr[1] &&
        req.url != methodArr[2] &&
        req.url != methodArr[3] &&
        req.url != methodArr[4] &&
        req.url != methodArr[5]
    ) {
        allowedMethod = false;
    }`

but still same logic error

Comment: note that the http methods are [well defined](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_methods)

Comment: You check method but you use req.url, that is wrong.

Comment: The right error code is `405`

Comment: Thanks Evert :) will apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
req.method
```

instead of

```
req.url
```

in condition.

```
if (
    req.method != methodArr[0] &&
    req.method != methodArr[1] &&
    req.method != methodArr[2] &&
    req.method != methodArr[3] &&
    req.method != methodArr[4] &&
    req.method != methodArr[5]
){
    allowedMethod = false;
}
```

Or you can use this code :

```
if(methodArr.indexOf(req.method) < 0){
    allowedMethod = false;
}
```